# error create model in CRUD generator gii yii2 framework

Tags: php, model, yii2, crud, gii

I have created a model class using Model generator Gii with namespace `common\models\Artikel` and there is no error but when I'm trying to create a model class using CRUD generator Gii, there is a error like this:

[image]

In my Models folder there is folder again named `Artikel` and then on `artikel.php` have that namespace `common\models\Artikel`. But I don't know why I get this error using CRUD generator.

Comment: It may be autoloading issue. Can you show this model file in in your project tree and share your autoloading rules in your `composer.json`?

Comment: Can you check if in that folder exsist Artikel model and if the file have that namespace

Comment: yeah it exist, so in my Models folder there is folder again named Artikel and then on artikel.php have that namespace common\models\Artikel .. but i don't know why its error using CRUD generator @GabrieleCarbonai

Comment: you "models folder" is in which folder? the file must to be inside common\models folders and not in models\Artikel folders. Are you using base app or advanced one?

Comment: if is inside Arkitel folder, is missing the file name. In this case supposing the file Arkitel.php is inside common\models\Arkitel, you must to write in CRUD the structure folder plus file name: common\models\Arkitel\Arkitel

Comment: oh im using advance template and i created a Artikel model inside common\models but i remember that when i created models in Model Generator i type **common\models\Artikel** in namespace.. and thats why inside my Models folder there is folder again named Artikel and in that folder there is Artikel.php ..   now when i create models in CRUD generator with **common\models\Artikel\Artikel** there is no error again.. @GabrieleCarbonai

Comment: yes because autoloader was looking for file named Arkitel.php inside models folder

Comment: thank you for helping @GabrieleCarbonai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaration of this class should be in `common/models/Artikel.php` and inside of it you should have:

```
namespace common\models;

class Artikel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    // ...
}
```

`Artikel` Should not be part of the namespace, it is class name.

Comment: ahh i remember when i created models in Model Generator i type **common\models\Artikel** in namespace, so inside models folder there is folder again named Artikel.. and now when i create models in CRUD generator there is no error again because i type **common\models\Artikel\Artikel** .. thank you for remind me about the class name because its my first time using yii2 framework